# setting a predicate for fetch request

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i'm using core data and in the function:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController()
```

i want to use a predicate that can let the NSFetchRequest return the managed objects that has a given relationship value. i tried this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongToS like[cd] %@", (S*)self.s];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

Note: 
- belongToS: relationship of type (S *)
- self.s is a managed object casted to type (S *) since it is of NSManagedObject and actually it's truly an object of type (S *).
```

when i run the code it doesn't return anything! how can i edit it to make it work? and is there any optimal solution for fetching objects that has the same relationship value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` in a predicate is only for comparing strings. To fetch all objects that are related to `self.s`, the following should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongToS = %@", self.s];
```

Comment: (This assumes that `belongToS` is a "to-one" relationship.)